# Searching for url paths containing "/" in Kibana/EllasticSearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to write a regex in Kibana (v 7.9.1) and I want to get all paths that are like /rest/requirements/<ID_HERE>/ and nothing else at the end. I would expect that the following would work:

```
"/rest/requirements/[0-9]*/"
```

After several tests, I noticed that the following query don't work either: `"/rest/requirements/"`

While if I do `.*requirements.*`, for example, it works.

So there is something with "/" that I cannot understand. I tried the following as well without success:

```
.rest.requirements.*
//rest//requirements.*
\/rest\/requirements.*
\\rest\\requirements.*
```

Btw, I am using the filter as Query DSL as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add sample document or data ?

Comment: what is field type on which you are trying to search regex ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved:

For some reason, that specific regex I mention on the question was not working with that JSON I was passing. But was working for other types. No idea why yet.
The following, however, worked just fine:

```
{
  "regexp": {
    "path.keyword": ".*/requirements/[0-9]*/"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Regex is term based query and it will do match on entire value. In your original query, you are just using `path` as field name and it is text type of field hence it is not working because your path is analyze and tokenize by elasticsearch so it is not keeping exact path. Now, it is working because you are usingn`path.keyword` which is keyword type of field and elasticsearch dont apply any analyzer and tokenizer on keyword type of field hence it will keep your path value as it is and store in Elasticsearch.